# Extract separate grouped DataFrames from another DataFrame

Tags: julia

What is the best/most idiomatic way to extract groups into separate `DataFrames`? This would be useful in many ways (e.g. training separate models for each group, data visualization of each group, saving specific subsets of the data etc.)

A minimal example of such a problem could be:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(Dict(:groups => ["A", "B", "A"],
                    :val1 => [1, 2, -4],
                    :val2 => [3, 9, 1]))
```

The ideal output would be something like:

```
group_dict = Dict("A" => DataFrame(Dict(:val1 => [1, -4], :val2 => [3, 1])),
                  "B" => DataFrame(Dict(:val1 => [2], :val2 => [9])))
```

A clean solution would be leveraging `Query.jl`'s `@groupby`:

```
using Query
df |> @groupby(_.groups) |> ?? |> Dict
```

However, I'm stuck on the last step (i.e. turning this into a dictionary or some other named collection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DataFrames.groupby(df,:groups)` to return a GroupedDataFrame, which is a collection of SubDataFrames.

Comment: this is the recommended way, and with https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/pull/1908 merged (which will be soon) you will be able to index it by the values.

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(Dict(:groups => ["A", "B", "A"],
                    :val1 => [1, 2, -4],
                    :val2 => [3, 9, 1]))

dict = Dict([letter => df[df[!, :groups] .== letter, 2:3]
    for letter in unique(df[!, :groups])])

println(dict)
```

yields

```
Dict(
"B" => 1×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ val1  │ val2  │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ 9     │,

"A" => 2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ val1  │ val2  │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 3     │
│ 2   │ -4    │ 1     │)
```

which looks like what you needed. Note you need unique() in the comprehension statement  because unlike the dataframe groupby, the Dict has the restriction that it needs the :groups to be unique as keys.